# Releasing MVC 4.0 project that uses bundling(<compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0">)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, bundle

Here are my bundels:

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                "~/Bootstrap/assets/js/jquery.js"));

    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                "~/Bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-transition.js",
                "~/Bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-alert.js",
                "~/Bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-modal.js",
                "~/Bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js",
                "~/Bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-scrollspy.js",
                "~/Bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-tab.js",
                "~/Bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js",
                "~/Bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-popover.js",
                "~/Bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-button.js",
                "~/Bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-collapse.js",
                "~/Bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-carousel.js",
                "~/Bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-typeahead.js",
                "~/Bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-affix.js",
                "~/Bootstrap/assets/js/application.js",
                "~/Bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap.js"
                ));

}
```

And here is part of the content from my _Layout page:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
...
```

When I try running this application I get js error that looks something like this

```
An Error has occurred in the script on this page
Object Expected
URL   http://servername/AppName/bundles/bootstrap?v=asdjisdjsincdjijadosJISJDIS_idosd
```

A similar question was asked here:
[Why is my CSS bundling not working with a bin deployed MVC4 app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11985431/why-is-my-css-bundling-not-working-with-a-bin-deployed-mvc4-app)

I tried adding this configuration to my web.config file as suggested in question that I referenced

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  <remove name="BundleModule" />
  <add name="BundleModule" type="System.Web.Optimization.BundleModule" />
</modules>
```

and I am still getting the same error.

If something is not clear please let me know and I will elaborate.
Thanks

Comment: are you rendering your jquery bundle before your bootstrap bundle? it's not shown in your code

Comment: are all of the scripts in your bundles third party ones?

Comment: No. Some of them are mine. I "solved" this problem by turning off bundling(not really solving it). I am planning on enabling it at the end of the project and coming back to this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Does Bundle folder exisit in your application?

Try:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Bootstrap/assets/js/jquery").Include(
            "~/Bootstrap/assets/js/jquery.js"));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap").Include(
```

http://www.mvccentral.net/Story/Details/articles/kahanu/stylebundle-403-error-solved

[MVC CSS not rendering in Visual Studio When debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14430057/mvc-css-not-rendering-in-visual-studio-when-debugging)