# MVC not rendering when using Mime Map

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, video-streaming

I have started to try to use video in my MVC project for the first time, using the html video tag. I've used a sample local mp4 file to test things out.

```
            <video controls="controls" width="500" id="video_contract">
                <source src="~/videos/samplevideo.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
            </video>
```

I couldn't get the mp4 to play and read that I had to use a mimeMap in the web.config file, as follows:

```
<staticContent>
     <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="video/mp4" />
</staticContent>
```

Once my project was published the video was fine in the test published project.

The problem is that my local development project stopped rendering images etc. I have researched the problem and found this [MVC CSS not rendering in Visual Studio When debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14430057/mvc-css-not-rendering-in-visual-studio-when-debugging) .

As per the instruction I removed the mimeMap command and all was good again. I still need to be able to show mp4 video, so how do I get around this problem?

Apologies if I have missed something obvious, but I am still new to ASP.net programming.

Thanks.

Comment: Try this and let me know. If it works, I'll post it as the answer: 

    `<staticContent>
        <remove fileExtension=".mp4" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="video/mp4" />
    </staticContent>`

Comment: You're welcome. I have posted the answer with some explanations.

Answer (score 0):

Before adding mime types into your application, it's better to remove the type you are adding first:

```
<staticContent> 
    <remove fileExtension=".mp4" /> 
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="video/mp4" /> 
</staticContent>
```

This is to avoid any conflict if the mime type is already configured on the server you are deploying to.

---

**OR** you can manually add or remove mime types on IIS
[image]

Click on `Mime Types` -> `Open Feature`

[image]